# If $X$ and $Y$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and if $|X|, |Y| < \infty$, show that $|XY| = \frac{|X||Y|}{|X \cap Y|}.$

Tags: group-theory

I have a question;

$X$ and $Y$ are subgroups of a group $G$. If $|X|, |Y| < \infty$, show that

$$|XY| = \frac{|X||Y|}{|X \cap Y|}.$$

but I can't really picture what it is talking about to even get started.

Is it to do with looking for different ways so combine the elements {x, y, xy} ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume $X$ and $Y$ are subgroups of some group?

Comment: Yes, sorry will edit that in now!

Comment: "Given finite sets $X,Y$, the count of elements in $XY$ is the count of elements in $X$ multiplied by the count of elements in $Y$ divided by the count of elements common to $X$ and $Y$."  That is how I would read the equation as it is written.  Does that help?

Comment: Hint: $XY = \bigcup_{x\in X}xY$.

Comment: @abiessu that's pretty much exactly what i've written down but can't see any further

Comment: so XY is the union of all left cosets of Y?

Comment: @Emily: No, only of cosets with representatives from $X$. The union of all cosets would be $G$

Comment: Given that they are groups, there is a group identity element $e$ of both groups, which means that each of $X,Y$ is a subset of $XY$ (which is a specific example of what @tobiaskildetoft wrote), among other subsets.

Comment: okay yes, i understand the XY= u Xy bit now. would i continue by using the fact;
xY=x'Y off x^-1x' is in Y?

Comment: @Emily: Yes, something like that. So, $xY=x'Y$ iff $x^{-1}x' \in Y$ or $x^{-1}x' \in X \cap Y$ (since $x,x' \in X$). So, $xY$ and $x'Y$ are distinct iff $x$ and $x'$ are from distinct cosets of $X$ by $X \cap Y$. And there are $|X|/|X \cap Y|$ such cosets.

Comment: So if I let x1,x2,x3,.....,xr be the distinct coset representatives of XnY in X, then I have something in my notes;

|X : XnY| = |X||XnY| ^ -1

would r equal that? not really sure what I am doing now!

Comment: and for every $x_i$ there are $|Y|$ elements in $XY$, and the formula follows, i think

Comment: how should i logically get from taking the x1,x2,.... distinct coset representatives to the formula |X : XnY| = |X||XnY| ^ -1?

Comment: $X \cap Y$ is a subgroup of $X$, hence the index of $X \cap Y$ in $X$ (denoted by $|X:X \cap Y|$) is the number of respective cosets, that is $|X| / |X \cap Y|$

Comment: and so showing that XY is a disjoint union proves the result?

Comment: @Emily You should post your new question in, well, a new question. This means that all of the current answers are complete. You can link back to this question in your new one if you want to (this might be a good idea actually, as it will help people to know what you understand).

Comment: Have done so, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I summarize some comments?

Cosets $xY$ (for $x \in X$) are either disjoint, or equal. Suppose $xY=x′Y$. It happens if and only if $x^{-1}x' \in Y$ or $x^{-1}x' \in X \cap Y$ (since $x,x' \in X$). So, $xY$ and $x′Y$ are disjoint iff $x$ and $x'$ are representatives of distinct cosets of $X$ by $X \cap Y$. And there are $|X|/|X \cap Y|$ such cosets. For every coset there are |Y| elements in $XY$, and the formula follows.

Comment: Thank you for this.
Could I just clarify something.
XY is the union of all left cosets of Y with representatives from X?

Comment: Yes, $XY=\{xy\:|\:x \in X, y \in Y \}= \bigcup_{x \in X} xY$ as Tobias mentioned

Comment: Thank you all very much! sorry I am so dumb i take a lot of explaining to grasp something!

Comment: so where exactly does the |Y| come from in the beginning equation;

|XY|=|X||Y|/|X /\ Y|
?

Comment: We have $|X|/|X \cap Y|$ representatives and for every such representative $|Y|$ elements in $Y$: $|XY|=|X|/|X \cap Y| \cdot |Y|=|X||Y|/|X \cap Y|$

Comment: Oh of course, thank you so much! i wish I was as clever as you!

Answer (score 2):

The point is that if $z\in X\cap Y$ then it is counted twice when you form $XY$, so when you consider the cardinality of $|XY|$ you must remove one of these occurrences. You do the numbers, and it turns out that when you remove them you end up with the formula you have given. To prove the formula, consider the natural map $f:X\times Y\rightarrow XY$ and work out its "kernel".

**Addendum:** As requested, I'll included some more detail. This detail will basically be the description of some technology and how to apply it. The proof is neater with the technology.

*The technology:* Define an equivalence relation on the set $X\times Y$ as follows: Set $(x_0, y_0)\sim (x_1, y_1)$ if and only if $x_0y_0=x_1y_1$. Note that $(x_0, y_0)\sim (x_1, y_1)$ is equivalent to $x_1^{-1}x_0=y_1y_0^{-1}$. It is therefore equivalent to the existence of an element $z\in X\cap Y$ such that $(x_0z, z^{-1}y_0)=(x_1, y_1)$. Denote the equivalence class containing $(x, y)$ by $\widehat{(x, y)}$.

*Step 1:* Prove that each equivalence class $\widehat{(x, y)}$ has cardinality $|X\cap Y|$.

*Step 2:* Prove that the map $\frac{X\times Y}{\sim}\rightarrow XY$, $\widehat{(x, y)}\mapsto xy$ is well-defined and a bijection (note that ${X\times Y}/{\sim}$ denotes the set of equivalence classes of $X\times Y$ under $\sim$).

*Step 3:* Conclude.

Comment: would it be possible for more description on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: @Emily I've added in a kind of worked proof. If you get stuck at any part then just say.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, in this theorem we are trying to remove the repetitions while defining $XY$.

For simplicity, let's assume that $X\cap Y = \phi$. In this case, the total number of combinations you will get for elements in $XY$ is, $|X|\times |Y|$ (For every element in $Y$, there are $|X|$ elements in $X$.

Now if, there are $k$ elements in $X\cap Y$, then $$\forall x \in X-(X \cap Y),  \forall y \in Y-(X \cap Y), $$ Every element $xy \in XY$ can be written as $ xh_{1}h_{1}^{-1}y, xh_{2}h_{2}^{-1}y, xh_{3}h_{3}^{-1}y..., xh_{k}h_{k}^{-1}y$, where $h_{1}, h_{2}... h_{k} \in X \cap Y$. So to account for these repititions, we divide it it by $|X \cap Y|$.