# Needing help picturing the group idea 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[Needing help picturing the group idea.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518838/needing-help-picturing-the-group-idea)

A further extension relating to the question.

Give an example where $XY$ is not a subgroup of G, where $X$ and $Y$ are subgroups of $G$. Show that $XY$ is a subgroup if $XY=YX$. Hence show in particular that $XY$ is a subgroup if either $X$ or $Y$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What've you done so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I've shown |XY|=|X||Y|/|XnY| which was the start of the question but not sure how to use this with these next questions.

Comment: @Emily Given any subset $H$ of a group $G$, how will you show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$? The fact that $|XY|=|X||Y|/|X \cap Y|$ is not possible to show $XY$ is a subgroup of $G$. This is use to count the number of elements in the set $XY$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $S_3$ and let $X=\{e,(1\;2)\}$ and $Y=\{e,(1\;3)\}$. Then $XY=\{e,(1\;2),(1\;3),(1\;3\;2)\}$, which is not a subgroup of $S_3$.

Other questions are available in any standard book.